# Nier:Automata on Quadro P620 not working not even with all graphic options set to low

Tags: nier-automata

I am trying to run Nier:Automata on a workstation laptop - which I know is not dedicated in the first place for gaming- but nevertheless it should run the game smoothly with not much of high resolution stuff (texturing, FPS, resolution...etc.).

I tried to set all the settings to the lowest possible settings or even turn them off when possible but the game is lagging way to much. there is no broken pixels or such in the frame rate but rather everything is going just like in slow-motion!

What was more surprising that on another laptop, which is quite old, that has GeForce940M the game runs - yeah also slow- but much smoother than on the Quadro and even with better rendering.

Am I missing some settings maybe?

Comment: Are you playing the Steam version, or the BECOME AS GODS Edition from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: For what it's worth, Quadros run much more slowly than GeForce cards because of their drivers, which prioritize rendering accuracy over speed, hence why Quadros "aren't dedicated for gaming".

Comment: the steam version. I am aware of the some of the difference between Quadro and GeForce nevertheless I've read on the internet that anyhow a Quadro should run games to some extent with no problems in comparison to their equals of GeForce series.
but is it really that bad/limited so that I cannot even run the game in low settings and a 4-5 years old GeForce performs better than it?

Comment: I've just done some research, and it seems the P620 should perform much better than the 940M in games, though none of the sites I found mentioned whether they used Quadro drivers or GeForce ones. From what I know, you can use GeForce drivers with Quadro cards in order to get a huge performance boost in games. I don't know how to do it, though, nor how easy or convenient it is.